# Why does QGIS show too many labels per feature?

Tags: qgis, labeling

When i check to label polygon feature, one out of a total five polygons shows like 10 labels on top of it. That particular polygon is only one polygon, represented by one row in the table, so i dont see why it shows 10 labels on top of it.....?

I havent selected any advanced label options, that could have maybe created a conflict.

Any idea anyone?

I know that in ArcGIS there is an option; show only one label per feature - BUT there no setting like that in qgis, that i have found.

a screen of the problem

[image]

Comment: That shouldn't happen, QGIS will only label a feature with one label.  Can you provide an example data set?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of a) the labeled polygon b) the label menue with your settings pls? Would be easier to help then I think.

Answer (score 9):

If you use new labeling (from labeling toolbar) instead of the old version (in layer properties), the problem should go away.

The new version actually has an option called "label every part of multi-part feature" which should be similar to what Arcgis offers.

Comment: Alrighty - thanx it worked fine using the new tool. The old one kept giving me that problem. Tanks for the fast response!!!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with rule-based styling. It will only display labels for every part of a multi-part polygon. I'm using the Label Toolbar, the "label every part" box is not checked. It's only one rule so I solved it with a text box in the map, but that's not a long-tern solution.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the "Layer Styling" toolbar (by clicking on the paint-brush button above the list of layers in your project), click on the "Labels" button on the left side of the toolbar (looks like a "tag"). In the drop-down (almost at the top) where it indicates (and you probably chose "Single Labels" like I did), change it to indicate "Rule-Based Labeling".  For me, a box with two "check-boxes" then appears, with "(no filter)" indicated by each check-box.  These two boxes control what gets displayed.  I un-checked first one, then the other box and the first, then second, labels disappear!!

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer?

Comment: This answer does not make sense.  At 3.8.3 the Rule-Based Labeling doesn't have two check boxes.